# Why RxJava2 does not emitter data to the thread

Tags: java, rx-java, rx-java2

I have read the RxJava's doc. and try the demo below:
The Output is **d = [0]d = false**

May I know the reason that: why the data does not emitter to the `Observer`

RxJava version: `2.2.6`

```
        Observable.just("aa","bbb")
                .observeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                .map(s -> {
                    System.out.println("s = [" + s + "]");
                    return s.toUpperCase();
                })
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.single())
                .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .subscribe(new Observer<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {
                        System.out.println("d = [" + d + "]"+"d = "+ d.isDisposed());
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNext(String s) {
                        System.out.println("s = [" + s + "]");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onComplete() {

                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 1):

With all the thread switches you have added to your subscription your subscription is not running on the main thread anymore. This also means that nothing is stopping the main thread anymore and you application quits before it could print the data you want.

For testing purposes you can add a `Thread.sleep(1000);` at the end of your `main()` method (where I suppose you have added this code). Then you will see the output from the `System.out.println()` statements. Other solutions are to not use `subscribeOn()` or `observeOn()` and stay on the current thread. Also, you can use `blockingSubscribe()` to wait for the subscription to finish before continuing on the main thread.